# Error: Cannot find module '@discordjs/opus'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js, opus

Everytime i run my discord speech recognition code it goes online but as soon as it join the channel my code shows  Error: Cannot find module '@discordjs/opus'

```
Require stack:
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\util\loader.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\Opus.js  
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\index.js 
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\index.js      
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BasePlayer.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BroadcastAudioPlayer.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\VoiceBroadcast.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\ClientVoiceManager.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js      
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\index.js
Error: Cannot find module 'node-opus'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\util\loader.js       
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\Opus.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\index.js        
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\index.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BasePlayer.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BroadcastAudioPlayer.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\VoiceBroadcast.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\ClientVoiceManager.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js      
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\index.js
Error: Cannot find module 'opusscript'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\util\loader.js       
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\Opus.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\index.js        
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\index.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BasePlayer.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BroadcastAudioPlayer.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\VoiceBroadcast.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\ClientVoiceManager.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js      
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\index.js
2021-01-26T04:50:28.411Z :: discordClient message: Error: Error: Cannot find module '@discordjs/opus'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\util\loader.js       
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\Opus.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\index.js        
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\index.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BasePlayer.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BroadcastAudioPlayer.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\VoiceBroadcast.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\ClientVoiceManager.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js      
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\index.js
Error: Cannot find module 'node-opus'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\util\loader.js       
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\Opus.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\index.js        
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\index.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BasePlayer.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BroadcastAudioPlayer.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\VoiceBroadcast.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\ClientVoiceManager.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js      
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\index.js
Error: Cannot find module 'opusscript'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\util\loader.js       
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\Opus.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\opus\index.js        
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\index.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BasePlayer.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BroadcastAudioPlayer.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\VoiceBroadcast.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\ClientVoiceManager.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js      
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js
- C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\index.js
```

Also while installing required modules/libraries it shows that somehow it can't install discord/opus

```
> @discordjs/opus@0.1.0 install C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.1.0/opus-v0.1.0-node-v83-win32-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for @discordjs/opus@0.1.0 and node@14.15.4 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:225:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:327:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)  
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)       
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\SURYASH\\Desktop\\DiscordSpeechBot\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\opus\\prebuild\\node-v83-win32-x64\\opus.node" "--module_name=opus" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\SURYASH\\Desktop\\DiscordSpeechBot\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\opus\\prebuild\\node-v83-win32-x64" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v83-win32-x64\opus.node --module_name=opus --module_path=C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v83-win32-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\SURYASH\\Desktop\\DiscordSpeechBot\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus  
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v83-win32-x64\opus.node --module_name=opus --module_path=C:\Users\SURYASH\Desktop\DiscordSpeechBot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v83-win32-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @discordjs/opus@0.1.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @discordjs/opus@0.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SURYASH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-26T04_57_11_574Z-debug.log
```

So eventually my bot code require opus module and somehow it cant install it.

Comment: Install Python and try again.

Comment: `@discordjs/opus` is only a peer dependency of that `prism-media` package so not auto-installed (at least prior to npm@7). Did you remember to add it as a dep.?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
npm install discordjs/opus
```

I had the same issue "Error: Cannot find module '@discordjs/opus'" when trying to get my discord js bot to play an .mp3 file when a certain user was speaker

Figured this solution out by watching this video.
[youtube.com/watch?v=WXohhIJ1-f4](http://youtube.com/watch?v=WXohhIJ1-f4)

If you don't want to click on the link, just search "How to play audio in voice channel discord js" on youtube!

Comment: It is helpful to post the solution rather than linking to an external solution.

Answer (score 3):

first you need to install python,after that run this(admin powershell):

```
npm install -g windows-build-tools
```

if this command doesnt fix your issue (node-gyp issue)than

```
# before installing node-gyp on windows
    npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
    
    # install node-gyp globally
    npm install -g node-gyp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try installing this: `npm install --global windows-build-tools` with an admin powershell.  windows-build-tools installs python with it.

Answer (score 1):

open powershell(admin)
and type:

```
npm install -g windows-build-tools
```

before installing node-gyp on windows
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

install node-gyp globally
npm install -g node-gyp

Answer (score 1):

First install python from https://www.python.org/downloads/. That seems to be the main problem
When installing make sure to select `Add python to path`

[how to add python to path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VZ6N.png)

Close the terminal reopen it, then try again.

If it still doesn't work, open windows power-shell as admin, and type `npm i -g windows-build-tools`

Close the terminal reopen and try downloading the packages again