# Error: Cannot find module '@discordjs/opus' on pm2

Tags: visual-studio-code, discord.js, node-modules, pm2, opus

I am having some issues with discord.js/opus.
So I am having the same error as this guy : [Error: Cannot find module '@discordjs/opus'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896154/error-cannot-find-module-discordjs-opus) but on pm2. When I run it with the Visual Studio Code Debugger it's work but it's keep disappearing the folder when I reopen the file later so I just copy it from my user folder on my computer. When I run it on pm2 it's say the opus folder is not there.

Comment: Install it with npm or yarn in the project folder. It has to be referenced in package.json and package.lock.json in order for pm2 to know it exists. Moving npm packages by hand may result in major errors.

Comment: As you mentioned the question is already exist so, please use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896154/error-cannot-find-module-discordjs-opus for review your question.